# DDD - Value Object CRUD

Tags: domain-driven-design, value-objects

I am working in a task management application where users can open tickets. Each ticket has a **short description** field that can be chosen from a list. Backoffice team can eventually add, remove or update **short description list**. Changes in **short description list** must **NOT** affect already created tickets.

I think **short description** is a VO from the ticket perspective but also an entity from the CRUD perspective.

Should I model two separated objects with tow separated repositories? One for the VO (read-only) and other for CRUD? What about code replication?

Answer (score 1):

> I think short description is a VO from the ticket perspective but also an entity from the CRUD perspective.

That's a bit suspicious; I would guess that the `short descriptions` are value objects, but the `current list of approved short descriptions` is an entity.

Which is to say that the back office team is modifying a document, and the ticket includes a value that was copied from that document when the ticket was created.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it right, you have two models in two bounded contexts. One could be a CRUD entity with various properties like `lastEditDate`, `creatorId`, `textRepresentatuon` and so on but in the `task management bc` it could be a simple `value object` containing a string. The data copying could be done in an Anti-coruption layer.